# Bootstrap input form into a paragraph

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to fit an input form into a paragraph using Bootstrap. However, it always jumps into a new line.

What I want is, more or less, is this:

[image: Good :)]

But, I get this:

[image: Bad :(]

What can I do? Here's my code:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div id="text" class="form-inline">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod...</p>
  <div class="input-group">
    <select class="form-control" id="sel1" style="width:auto;">
      <option>nope</option>
      <option selected>tempor</option>
      <option>not this one</option>
      <option>wrong</option>
    </select>
    <span class="input-group-addon" style="width:auto;">select option</span>
  </div>
  <p>...incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
  <br>
</div>
```

Comment: It will go into the next line because `<div>` and `<p>` are block elements

Answer (score 0):

Add `style="display: inline"` to both `<p>` elements and `style="display: inline-block"` to `class="input-group"`.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div id="text" class="form-inline">
  <p style="display: inline">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod...</p>
  <div class="input-group" style="display: inline-block">
    <select class="form-control" id="sel1" style="width:auto;">
      <option>nope</option>
      <option selected>tempor</option>
      <option>not this one</option>
      <option>wrong</option>
    </select>
    <span class="input-group-addon" style="width:auto;">select option</span>
  </div>
  <p style="display: inline">...incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
  <br>
</div>
```

Comment: This would be better if you could use OP's code to demonstrate your answer instead of an image

Comment: I originally added it but it had formatting issues and was not displaying in the answer. It is working now.

Comment: No wonder the `<select>` has a different appearance, I forgot to include Bootstrap.

Comment: Doesn't work. This is what I get: http://imgur.com/xaT0wyJ
The span class="input-group-addon" has different size than the form control. Besides, they're only in the same line if the screen width is too large. That's not going to happen on mobile.

Comment: Besides, I got all the text center aligned, by copying your code, and I don't understand why :(

Answer (score 0):

Best way to display block element like `<p>`and `<div>`in a same line is to use `inline block`. you can use `inline` too. 
But the main **difference** in between inline and inline-block is that,
 `inline-block` allows you to specify the dimensions, padding, and margins of the element whereas `inline` simply wraps the element.

Here is a [working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/275ya7sj/)

CSS:

```
#block1, #block2, #block3
{
    display:inline-block;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="text" class="form-inline">
  <p id="block1">Lorem ipsum ....</p>
  <div id="block2">
  <div class="input-group">
    <select class="form-control" id="sel1" style="width:auto;">
      <option>nope</option>
      <option selected>tempor</option>
      <option>not this one</option>
      <option>wrong</option>
    </select>
    <span class="input-group-addon" style="width:auto;">select option</span>
  </div>
   </div>
  <p id="block3">...inct labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>

</div>
```

** Remove some of your text to understand functionality properly.

Comment: The form and the text are in the same line ONLY if the text is short (like in your example), but will not fit if the screen has small width (like on mobile).

Comment: it is an expected behavior ... after `p` tag if don't have enough space  `div` will show at new line but actually those elements were inline.